# thenReturn not returning expected values

Tags: mockito

```
@Component
public class RefValidator implements Component {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;


    public void validate(Context context) {
        Txn txn = context.getTxn();
        if (Objects.nonNull(txn) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(txn.getReferenceNumber())){            
             if(txn.getId() == 0){
                boolean isRealmIdAndReferenceNumberExists = repository.isRefNumberExistsInSale(txn.getRealmId(), txn.getReferenceNumber());
                if(isRealmIdAndReferenceNumberExists){
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have a class as above and want to test it using mockito. I am doing `@INjectMock` for `RefValidator` and `@Mock` on `Repository` but when I do

```
Mockito
    .when(repository.isRefNumberExistsInSale(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString()))
    .thenReturn(true);
```

`thenReturn` doesn't return *true*.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `Txn` definition? Specifically, the types returned by `getRealmId()` and `txn.getReferenceNumber()`.

Comment: Aside from what @glytching is suggesting, you can do a step by step debug inside the method, and check that you are actually reaching the `repository.isRefNumberExistsInSale(txn.getRealmId(), txn.getReferenceNumber());` line. Maybe if branches out in the 2 `ifs` above it...

Comment: I am able to step into the method and able to reach out to method.Txn returns string for both realmIn and reference number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda hard to define what's the problem because you haven't provided your test class. But it looks like your annotations are not being processed while running a test suit.

Try one of the following:

- Add `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` above your test class
- Add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` inside setup method (which is annotated with `@Before`)

See the 2nd section of [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations) for help.